# Background for html back that is fixed for the screen

Tags: html, css, background

I'm working on a basic html page and I have this background image bg.jpg.
But the problem is depending on the screen size you have and how many pixels the screen has I'm not able to view the whole background image which is something I want.

How do I make the background fixed so you can see the whole background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a full page background image than you can simply do it with CSS3 `background-size` property

```
body { 
  background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you need to attach it, kinda fixed and shouldn't be scrolled, than use

```
background-attachment: fixed; 
/* This is already used in above CSS declaration using CSS Short Hand*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can read more here: [link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your "body background image code" then paste this code:

```
html 
{ 
        background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed #000; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS pseudo selectors.

```
body:after
{
    content: url(your_image)
    /* Styling your image here just like a div */
}
```

Of course those other solutions are OK too, but they only work in latest modern browsers. This pseudo selection solution works in most browsers used today. If you'd like to support even older browsers, like ancient versions of IE, then you can use a div to contain the background image and style it as you'd like.